# PhpMyAdmin и HTML

Tags: html, phpmyadmin

Пишу сайт. Создал несколько таблиц в phpmyadmin. В этом div нужно попросить у базы данных информацию о таблице menu, чтоб она вывела список ссылок меню.

```
    <div id="block_menu" >  
            ***     
    </div>
```

Не знаю, как попросить эти данные. Помогите, пожалуйста, что надо написать?

Comment: ,1. на php? 2. Хотите вывести все записи, или только конкретные? 3. Напишите какие поля есть в таблице, чтобы понять по каким данным можно делать выборку.

Comment: Попросите вежливо: "Дай пожалуйста".

Comment: Вывести все записи. Есть поля: id, link, name. Как я понял, так id - просто укажет в ссылке номер, link - как раз сама ссылка, а name - название пункта меню (главная, новости и т.д

Comment: HTML не язык программирования и не умеет читать с базы

Comment: Вот так и помогай потом людям...

Answer (score 0):

Если на php, то вот накидал пример с комментариями. 
***Важно*** - пример только для демонстрации. В боевом проекте подключения к БД обязательно надо скрывать. 
Файл подключения к БД `bdconnect.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: 640kb
 * Date: 16/01/2020
 * Time: 16:48
 */

//Настраиваем подключение к базе данных
$servername = "ip сервера"; // ip
$username = "user"; // Имя пользователя mysql (Не забудьте, что у него должны быть права на нужную таблицу)
$password = "password."; //Пароль для пользователя user
$db = "Database"; // Название базы данных, к которой подключаетесь.
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db); // Выполняем подключение

if (!$conn) { // Проверяем подключение к БД.
    printf("Невозможно подключиться к базе данных. Код ошибки: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu"; // Можно добавить WHERE id>'1', чтобы искать по id или диапазону. Где menu - это название таблицы, к которой подключаетесь.
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Файл главной страницы `index.php`

```
<?php

require_once "bdconnect.php";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ // выводим все данные по очереди для каждой записи в БД.
    $ID = $row['id']; // Получаем id из таблицы БД
    $Name = $row['name']; // Получаем name из таблицы БД
    $Link = $row['link']; // Получаем link из таблицы БД
    // Выводим в интерфейс.
    echo '<div id="block_menu" >
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <td id="name">' . $Name . '</td>
            <td id="link">' . $Link . '</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>';
}
```

Comment: У меня настройки базы в отдельном документе, код: <?
$db_login='root';
$db_pass='root';
$db_name='site';
$db_server='localhost';
$db_connect=mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_login, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) { 
    printf("Невозможно подключиться к базе данных. Код ошибки: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
?>

Comment: Потом код для таблицы из меню отдельная страница: 
<?
$q=mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT * FROM menu");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($q);
do{
 echo '<li><a href="'$r["link"].'">'.$r["name"].;'</a></li>';
}
while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($q));
?>
А главная страница идет отдельно. И в главную страницу нужно куда-то вставить обращение к базе. Чтоб в блоке страницы выводились ссылки

Comment: В самом верху добавляете require_once "Имя файла с подлючением";

Comment: Безо всяких знаков?

Comment: @ДмитрийБлагодер  добавил в ответ пример.

Comment: Добавил код в главный код, вылезли ошибки:

Warning: require_once(bd_connect.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\home\localhost\www\index.php on line 19

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'bd_connect.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in F:\home\localhost\www\index.php on line 19

Comment: Ну так Вы вместо `bd_connect.php` указывайте свой файл подключения к базе данных.

Comment: И файлы должны лежать в одном месте. У Вас файл `index` лежит в `F:\home\localhost\www\`, а путь к файлу `bd_connect` указан через `(include_path='.;C:\php\pear')`, что явно находится в другом месте.

Comment: Проверил все, вроде бы все файлы в 1 папке, ничего не потерялось. А (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') этот путь откуда взялся? Не понимаю

Comment: Добавьте в файл `index.php` `ini_set('include_path', 'F:\home\localhost\www\');` Или добавлять путь к файлу `db_connect` require("F:\home\localhost\www\bd_connect.php");

Comment: Ругается на синтаксические ошибки

Comment: Дмитрий, у нас на сайте принято оформлять один вопрос одной темой. Ваш уже достаточно разросся, рекомендую оформить новый вопрос, при необходимости дав ссылку на текущий.